# How to place 3D object at GPS coordinates with ARkit

Tags: swift, arkit

Working with Project Dent trying to put 3d object at absolute GPS coordinates.

Readme shows how to put a 2D information annotation object into AR space, but I can't get it to place 3D object at GPS coordinates

Project Dent doesn't use standard SceneView, which makes it hard to try and do this based on a lot of the tutorials out there. It uses SceneLocationView based on ARCL

Here's the sample code for a 2D annotation

```swift
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.504571, longitude: -0.019717)
let location = CLLocation(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: 300)
let view = UIView() // or a custom UIView subclass

let annotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: location, view: view)

sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: annotationNode)
```

Here's what I've been trying to do to get it to work with a 3D object

```swift
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.504571, longitude: -0.019717)
let location = CLLocation(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: 300)
let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

let objectNode = LocationNode(location: location, SCNbox: box)

sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: objectNode)
```

Ideally, I'd like this code to simply place 3d box at these GPS coordinates in AR space.

Sadly, I can't even get it to build at present.

As an update to this, I've done the following. Create a new class in Nodes, based on LocationNode, called ThreeDNode -

```swift
open class ThreeDNode: LocationNode {

   // Class for placing 3d objects in AR space
   public let threeDObjectNode: LocationNode

   public init(location: CLLocation?, scene: SCNScene) {

       let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
       //let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)

       threeDObjectNode = LocationNode(location: location)
       threeDObjectNode.geometry = boxGeometry
       threeDObjectNode.removeFlicker()

       super.init(location: location)

       addChildNode(threeDObjectNode)
   }

   required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
```

and then in POIViewController, tried to place 3d object in AR space with following code -

```
//example using 3d box object
        let coordinate2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.010339, longitude: -8.351157)
        let location2 = CLLocation(coordinate: coordinate2, altitude: 300)

        let asset = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        let object = ThreeDNode(location: location2, scene: asset)

        //add to scene with confirmed location
        sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: object)
```

No joy :( Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a location node, and add your box as its geometry, or as a child node:

```
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)

let locationNode = LocationNode(location: location)
locationNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: locationNode)
```

I didn't run this code in Xcode so you may need to tweak.

Comment: do you mean to add this to my class file ThreeDNode, or directly to the View Controller? thanks

Comment: I added the box object directly to view controller and it compiles, but still doesn't appear in the app, and the exact same thing works for the same coordinates with 2d object!

Comment: @MossyOMahony did you get this to work? I did what this answer suggests and I'm able to see my 3d model in ar. However, it seems like it's not fixed to the coordinates since the model moves with my camera and doesn't stick to the given gps location when I move away.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit late to this conversation, but I am working on something similar. Placing the object is the more straight forward part. You'll need to create a scene object and add to the the scene view, and add all that to an anchor. Then it'll show in real space and stay anchored in place.

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "name of your scn asset")!
          if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "name of the scn assets root node", recursively: true){
             sceneNode.position = cameraPosition //this'll place the object at the camera's position
              sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sceneNode)
```

within the function
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

```
        // Place content only for anchors found by plane detection.
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
    
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
    
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: planeAnchor.center.x, y: 0, z: planeAnchor.center.z)
    
        planeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-.pi/2, 1, 0, 0)
        
        // Add the visualization to the ARKit-managed node so that it tracks
        // changes in the plane anchor as plane estimation continues.
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

The trickier bit is getting it to appear at a given GPS location. At app launch, the device's local space is at 0,0. You have to be able to convert the GPS coords to real world coords and then convert that to the device's local space. There are a number of sites that have the math for it, although I've not been able to get it to work yet either.